# How to install Oracle using saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to Saltstack, Just want to know is there any way we can install oracle on CentOS-6 using salt master?

Any guideline will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can *always* end up with a shell script that provisions your server using salt. But if you want to monitor and change the running server in production, you might want to solve it a bit smarter.

Independently you should at least know how to install everything on your distribution without saltstack. As far as i can remember oracle does some things different from other vendors, but the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/toc.htm) seems quite detailed, and a short google search for oracle together with centos gives you a bunch of results.

Afterwards check whats available in saltstack respecting oracle. There is [not yet a oracle formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=oracle), but the [builtin states](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/index.html) should provide enough possibilities to write the deployment. There is [a module available](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.oracle.html). It does not help you installing oracle, but it might be useful later, when you want to maintain it. Depending on your needs you might want to have a look at several other features and subsystems, [this page in the development documentation of saltstack](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/modular_systems.html) gives a nice overview about all the different names and the idea behind it (in very short). for further explanation you should read the corresponding chapters in the salt docs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) I will go through the same